# Atomic load to multiple tables in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do a load operation in bigquery from GCS files using `load_job` in ruby.

The problem is, when I have multiple files in GCS affecting different tables, there's a chance some might fail due to validation/network issues, leading to inconsistent data in bigquery.
Let's say I want to load last hour data which is stored in 5 files, even if 1 of these load jobs fail, I'll be having bad data for analytics.

Is there a way I can batch all these load jobs in a single atomic request to bigquery?

Comment: you share some code how you are trying to do it. are you able to catch failures and retry in case of error ? What about a temporary table to ensure move the data properly to bigquery and after that move them to your final tables?

Comment: @hlagos, even if I create temporary tables, these problems will still exist when sending the copy request because they will also create different jobs in BQ, or am I missing something with that approach?

Comment: if your concern is about network errors submiting to BQ, it shouldn't be a case if you ensure that all your data is inside of bigquery, I would expect it to be much more stable once all your data is in temp tables inside bigquery and perform the operations from table to table

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a BQ Sink or streaming data into BQ.
With Sinks you will be counting on the BQ underlining architecture which is quite stable and consistent to move data from text files to BQ tables.
With streaming data, you will have more control over your transactions. You can then insure that you're data is moved correctly line by line.

Comment: The reason not to go for streaming is that loading is much faster when there's a lot of data, and streaming will slow down the process.

Comment: Why don't you try to send your data to Cloud Datastore as your temp location since datastore supports ACID transactions and then after successful transaction send the data from the resulting datastore kind to the BQ table. More info can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore

Comment: We started working on a project today using dataflow that might be a help for you in the scenario you described.